# How to get directory size in PHP

Tags: php, filesystems

```
function foldersize($path) {
  $total_size = 0;
  $files = scandir($path);

  foreach($files as $t) {
    if (is_dir(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t)) {
      if ($t<>"." && $t<>"..") {
          $size = foldersize(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t);

          $total_size += $size;
      }
    } else {
      $size = filesize(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t);
      $total_size += $size;
    }
  }
  return $total_size;
}

function format_size($size) {
  $mod = 1024;
  $units = explode(' ','B KB MB GB TB PB');
  for ($i = 0; $size > $mod; $i++) {
    $size /= $mod;
  }

  return round($size, 2) . ' ' . $units[$i];
}

$SIZE_LIMIT = 5368709120; // 5 GB

$sql="select * from users order by id";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $disk_used = foldersize("C:/xampp/htdocs/freehosting/".$row['name']);

  $disk_remaining = $SIZE_LIMIT - $disk_used;
  print 'Name: ' . $row['name'] . '<br>';

  print 'diskspace used: ' . format_size($disk_used) . '<br>';
  print 'diskspace left: ' . format_size($disk_remaining) . '<br><hr>';
}
```

[php disk_total_space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466140/php-disktotalspace#466268)

Any idea why the processor usage shoot up too high or 100% till the script execution is finish ? Can anything be done to optimize it? or is there any other alternative way to check folder and folders inside it size?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The following are other solutions [offered elsewhere](http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=1527717&postcount=4):

If on a Windows Host:

```
<?
    $f = 'f:/www/docs';
    $obj = new COM ( 'scripting.filesystemobject' );
    if ( is_object ( $obj ) )
    {
        $ref = $obj->getfolder ( $f );
        echo 'Directory: ' . $f . ' => Size: ' . $ref->size;
        $obj = null;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'can not create object';
    }
?>
```

Else, if on a Linux Host:

```
<?
    $f = './path/directory';
    $io = popen ( '/usr/bin/du -sk ' . $f, 'r' );
    $size = fgets ( $io, 4096);
    $size = substr ( $size, 0, strpos ( $size, "\t" ) );
    pclose ( $io );
    echo 'Directory: ' . $f . ' => Size: ' . $size;
?>
```

Comment: Note that the ' ' in strpos is a tab

Comment: Source: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/get-directory-size-with-php-efficiently-361124.html

Comment: When I try this on a Windows host, I an error: `Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found`.

Comment: @vertigoelectric Make sure you've enabled the COM and .NET dll in your ini file. See comments on http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php for additional details.

Comment: Note that the Linux option can give you unwanted results, see [this question and the answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86985/60074).

Comment: If you need to know the OS - `PHP_OS` constant - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879043/php-script-detect-whether-running-under-linux-or-windows

Comment: `popen` mostly disabled for security reasons unless we have vps Any alternative to that?

Comment: Warning: if a hacker is able to choose the content of $f , this code is vulnerable to code execution. a hacker could make `$f` contain `./ & rm -rfv /` and delete everything. use escapeshellarg(): `$io = popen ( '/usr/bin/du -sk ' . escapeshellarg($f), 'r' );` instead.

Comment: remember that you need to escape the spaces in the path or use `preg_quote($path,' ')` to escape the spaces in the path otherwise the LINUX solution wont work

Comment: The size returned is in KB, not in B.

Answer (score 101):

```
function GetDirectorySize($path){
    $bytestotal = 0;
    $path = realpath($path);
    if($path!==false && $path!='' && file_exists($path)){
        foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)) as $object){
            $bytestotal += $object->getSize();
        }
    }
    return $bytestotal;
}
```

The same idea as Janith Chinthana suggested. 
With a few fixes:

- Converts `$path` to [realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)
- Performs iteration only if path is valid and folder exists
- Skips `.` and `..` files
- Optimized for performance

Comment: both of these raised a Runtime exception when they came across broken symlinks for me. A simple try/catch around the `$bytestotal += $object->getSize();` resolved this for me.

Comment: To get KBs instead of Bytes, then divide the data by `1024`

Comment: if the folder is empty , the code returns an error 
 Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::

Comment: Works for both Linux and Windows, folder doesn't exist returns 0 and if folder empty returns 0, not sure why @gr68 has issues, I think this should be the approved answer.

Comment: Maybe gr68 meant when the $path variable is empty. Recently I saw `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` throwing an error on an empty path, so, just in case, I've adopted the code to check folder existence.

Comment: I've upvoted this post because it answers the question, but I think its claim to be optimized for performance is unfulfilled.

Comment: @user10089632 You are right from a certain point of view. It has no visible "optimizations". Maybe I should have left that claim out. But I wanted to let people know in some way that I have actually measured and compared the performance of tons of different syntaxes and approaches, and this exact code came out as fastest.

Comment: @Programster Ignoring exceptions isn't too elegant solution in my opinion... But you can change that `try {} catch()` block to a conditional statement where you check the current element if it's a (regular) file: `if ( $object->isFile() ) { $bytestotal += $object->getSize(); }`

Comment: it still takes approx 81 seconds with a directory up to the size of 2.1 GB on windows as compared to using `$obj = new \COM('scripting.filesystemobject');` which does this in approx 1.8 secs

Comment: Some directory may have problem and cause this error. **Uncaught RuntimeException: SplFileInfo::getSize()** Use `if ($object->isReadable())` before `getSize()` can help.

Comment: Really useful, thank you! I added a divisor for MB and round param to shave off extra bytes. Much better than disk_total_space().

Answer (score 34):

directory size using php [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).

***This works with any platform which is having php 5 or higher version.***

```
/**
 * Get the directory size
 * @param  string $directory
 * @return integer
 */
function dirSize($directory) {
    $size = 0;
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)) as $file){
        $size+=$file->getSize();
    }
    return $size;
}
```

Comment: I found a bug in your code, this function add size of directory '..'. So, you have to limit it like this: `if($file -> getFileName() != '..') $size += $file -> getSize();`

Comment: @Alph.Dev suggested an improved version below. Check it out.

Answer (score 30):

A pure php example.

```
<?php
    $units = explode(' ', 'B KB MB GB TB PB');
    $SIZE_LIMIT = 5368709120; // 5 GB
    $disk_used = foldersize("/webData/users/vdbuilder@yahoo.com");

    $disk_remaining = $SIZE_LIMIT - $disk_used;

    echo("<html><body>");
    echo('diskspace used: ' . format_size($disk_used) . '<br>');
    echo( 'diskspace left: ' . format_size($disk_remaining) . '<br><hr>');
    echo("</body></html>");


function foldersize($path) {
    $total_size = 0;
    $files = scandir($path);
    $cleanPath = rtrim($path, '/'). '/';

    foreach($files as $t) {
        if ($t<>"." && $t<>"..") {
            $currentFile = $cleanPath . $t;
            if (is_dir($currentFile)) {
                $size = foldersize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            }
            else {
                $size = filesize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            }
        }   
    }

    return $total_size;
}


function format_size($size) {
    global $units;

    $mod = 1024;

    for ($i = 0; $size > $mod; $i++) {
        $size /= $mod;
    }

    $endIndex = strpos($size, ".")+3;

    return substr( $size, 0, $endIndex).' '.$units[$i];
}

?>
```

Comment: vdbuilder & @minitech : What about the *processor usage* issue raised by the OP?

Comment: @brasofilo The op ended the question with 'or is there any other alternative way to check folder and folders inside it size?' This is an alternative way. If this code is used the processor usage problems with the op's original code are irrelevant. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, vdbuilder. I just missed some textual explanation about why your code is an optimized version... As I used it to answer this [WordPress Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71054/12615) :o)

Answer (score 22):

```
function get_dir_size($directory){
    $size = 0;
    $files = glob($directory.'/*');
    foreach($files as $path){
        is_file($path) && $size += filesize($path);
        is_dir($path)  && $size += get_dir_size($path);
    }
    return $size;
}
```

Comment: short and simple

Comment: Perfect answer! Should be displayed before accepted answer. Bravo @Alex Kashin

Comment: takes 36 secs on windows platform to calculate a dir around 2.1 GB

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to Jonathan Sampson, Adam Pierce and Janith Chinthana I did this one checking for most performant way to get the directory size. Should work on Windows and Linux Hosts.

```
static function getTotalSize($dir)
{
    $dir = rtrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $dir), '/');

    if (is_dir($dir) === true) {
        $totalSize = 0;
        $os        = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3));
        // If on a Unix Host (Linux, Mac OS)
        if ($os !== 'WIN') {
            $io = popen('/usr/bin/du -sb ' . $dir, 'r');
            if ($io !== false) {
                $totalSize = intval(fgets($io, 80));
                pclose($io);
                return $totalSize;
            }
        }
        // If on a Windows Host (WIN32, WINNT, Windows)
        if ($os === 'WIN' && extension_loaded('com_dotnet')) {
            $obj = new \COM('scripting.filesystemobject');
            if (is_object($obj)) {
                $ref       = $obj->getfolder($dir);
                $totalSize = $ref->size;
                $obj       = null;
                return $totalSize;
            }
        }
        // If System calls did't work, use slower PHP 5
        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $totalSize += $file->getSize();
        }
        return $totalSize;
    } else if (is_file($dir) === true) {
        return filesize($dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for fastest multi-host solution
But should the OS-Checks be like if ($os !== 'WIN' && $os !== 'Win') and elseif (extension_loaded('com_dotnet'))

Comment: best optimized answer so far takes approx `1.3 secs` to calculate a dir around `2.16 GB` with approx `81,043 Files` and  `16,713 Folders` as compared to recursive iterator which sleeps for about `80 secs` (ON WINDOWS)

Comment: Works perfectly and efficient too .Should be below accepted :-)

Comment: Thanks man for such a nice function but as `popen` is mostly disabled on most hostings for security reasons is there any alternative to that .The rest is just perfect.

Answer (score 9):

Even though there are already many many answers to this post, I feel I have to add another option for unix hosts that only returns the sum of all file sizes in the directory (recursively).

If you look at Jonathan's answer he uses the `du` command. This command will return the total directory size but the pure PHP solutions posted by others here will return the sum of all file sizes. *Big difference!*

### What to look out for

When running `du` on a newly created directory, it may return `4K` instead of `0`. This may even get more confusing after having deleted files from the directory in question, having `du` reporting a total directory size that does not correspond to the sum of the sizes of the files within it. Why? The command `du` returns a report based on some file settings, as Hermann Ingjaldsson commented on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86985/60074).

### The solution

To form a solution that behaves like some of the PHP-only scripts posted here, you can use `ls` command and pipe it to `awk` like this:

```
ls -ltrR /path/to/dir |awk '{print \$5}'|awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum=sum+\$1} END {print sum}'
```

As a PHP function you could use something like this:

```
function getDirectorySize( $path )
{
    if( !is_dir( $path ) ) {
        return 0;
    }

    $path   = strval( $path );
    $io     = popen( "ls -ltrR {$path} |awk '{print \$5}'|awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum=sum+\$1} END {print sum}'", 'r' );
    $size   = intval( fgets( $io, 80 ) );
    pclose( $io );

    return $size;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found this approach to be shorter and more compatible. The Mac OS X version of "du" doesn't support the -b (or --bytes) option for some reason, so this sticks to the more-compatible -k option.

```
$file_directory = './directory/path';
$output = exec('du -sk ' . $file_directory);
$filesize = trim(str_replace($file_directory, '', $output)) * 1024;
```

Returns the $filesize in bytes.

Comment: Not a great solution after all, because this will give you unwanted and unexpected results, see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Johnathan Sampson's Linux example didn't work so good for me. Here's an improved version:

```
function getDirSize($path)
{
    $io = popen('/usr/bin/du -sb '.$path, 'r');
    $size = intval(fgets($io,80));
    pclose($io);
    return $size;
}
```

Comment: This will give you unexpected and unwanted results, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It works perfectly fine .

```
     public static function folderSize($dir)
     {
        $size = 0;

        foreach (glob(rtrim($dir, '/') . '/*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $each) {
            $func_name = __FUNCTION__;
            $size += is_file($each) ? filesize($each) : static::$func_name($each);
        }

        return $size;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are hosted on Linux:

```
passthru('du -h -s ' . $DIRECTORY_PATH)
```

It's better than foreach

Comment: As posted elsewhere on this Question, make sure `$DIRECTORY_PATH` isn't set by others (like people online etc). Someone could set it as `./ & rm -rfv /`, and it'd potentially wreak havoc. Haven't tested it, but he recommended: `escapeshellarg($DIRECTORY_PATH)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you could do to optimise the script - but maximum success would make it IO-bound rather than CPU-bound:

1. Calculate `rtrim($path, '/')` outside the loop.
2. make `if ($t<>"." && $t<>"..")` the outer test - it doesn't need to stat the path
3. Calculate `rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t` once per loop - inside 2) and taking 1) into account.
4. Calculate `explode(' ','B KB MB GB TB PB');` once rather than each call?

Answer (score 2):

### PHP get directory size (with FTP access)

After hard work, this code works great!!!! and I want to share with the community (by MundialSYS)

```
function dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $dir) {
    $size = 0;
    $files = ftp_nlist($ftpStream, $dir);

    foreach ($files as $remoteFile) {
        if(preg_match('/.*\/\.\.$/', $remoteFile) || preg_match('/.*\/\.$/', $remoteFile)){
            continue;
        }
        $sizeTemp = ftp_size($ftpStream, $remoteFile);
        if ($sizeTemp > 0) {
            $size += $sizeTemp;
        }elseif($sizeTemp == -1){//directorio
            $size += dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $remoteFile);
        }
    }

    return $size;
}

$hostname = '127.0.0.1'; // or 'ftp.domain.com'
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$startdir = '/public_html'; // absolute path
$files = array();
$ftpStream = ftp_connect($hostname);
$login = ftp_login($ftpStream, $username, $password);
if (!$ftpStream) {
    echo 'Wrong server!';
    exit;
} else if (!$login) {
    echo 'Wrong username/password!';
    exit;
} else {
    $size = dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $startdir);
}

echo number_format(($size / 1024 / 1024), 2, '.', '') . ' MB';

ftp_close($ftpStream);
```

Good code!
Fernando

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Johnathan Sampson's Linux example, watch out when you are doing an intval on the outcome of the "du" function, if the size is >2GB, it will keep showing 2GB.

**Replace:**

```
$totalSize = intval(fgets($io, 80));
```

**by:**

```
strtok(fgets($io, 80), " ");
```

supposed your "du" function returns the size separated with space followed by the directory/file name.

Answer (score 2):

Object Oriented Approach :

```
/**
 * Returns a directory size
 *
 * @param string $directory
 *
 * @return int $size directory size in bytes
 *
 */
function dir_size($directory)
{
    $size = 0;
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)) as $file)
    {
        $size += $file->getSize();
    }
    return $size;
}
```

Fast and Furious Approach :

```
function dir_size2($dir)
{
    $line = exec('du -sh ' . $dir);
    $line = trim(str_replace($dir, '', $line));
    return $line;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code adjusted to access main directory and all sub folders within it. This would return the full directory size.

```
function get_dir_size($directory){
    $size = 0;
    $files= glob($directory.'/*');
    foreach($files as $path){
        is_file($path) && $size += filesize($path);

        if (is_dir($path))
        {
            $size += get_dir_size($path);
        }
    }
    return $size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another function using native php functions.

```
function dirSize($dir)
    {
        $dirSize = 0;
        if(!is_dir($dir)){return false;};
        $files = scandir($dir);if(!$files){return false;}
        $files = array_diff($files, array('.','..'));

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if(is_dir("$dir/$file")){
                 $dirSize += dirSize("$dir/$file");
            }else{
                $dirSize += filesize("$dir/$file");
            }
        }
        return $dirSize;
    }
```

NOTE: [this function returns the files sizes, NOT the size on disk](https://superuser.com/questions/66825/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk)

Answer (score 0):

Evolved from Nate Haugs answer I created a short function for my project:

```
function uf_getDirSize($dir, $unit = 'm')
{
    $dir = trim($dir, '/');
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        trigger_error("{$dir} not a folder/dir/path.", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    if (!function_exists('exec')) {
        trigger_error('The function exec() is not available.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    $output = exec('du -sb ' . $dir);
    $filesize = (int) trim(str_replace($dir, '', $output));
    switch ($unit) {
        case 'g': $filesize = number_format($filesize / 1073741824, 3); break;  // giga
        case 'm': $filesize = number_format($filesize / 1048576, 1);    break;  // mega
        case 'k': $filesize = number_format($filesize / 1024, 0);       break;  // kilo
        case 'b': $filesize = number_format($filesize, 0);              break;  // byte
    }
    return ($filesize + 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner solution.  Result in bytes.

```
$size=array_sum(array_map('filesize', glob("{$dir}/*.*")));
```

Added bonus: you can simply change the file mask to whatever you like, and count only certain files (eg by extension).

Comment: warning, this solution fails on files not having a period in their name (like extension-less files): ```$ mkdir test
$ echo test >test/test_file_without_extension
$ php -r '$size=array_sum(array_map("filesize", glob("test/*.*")));var_dump($size);'```: int(0)

Comment: @hanshenrik, you can simply change the file mask for your case - or other cases as well.