# filesize() not showing actual size

Tags: php, filesize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP – get the size of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163456/php-get-the-size-of-a-directory)

I have 5 files in a directory and it shows file size = 4096 but when i delete 4 files and there is only 1 file left, it still shows the same size.
 that is how i am getting the file size

```
echo filesize("user_files/".$uid."/".$rs['DirectoryName']);
```

Comment: `filesize()` doesn't tell you the size of all files in the directory, just the size of the directory itself.

Answer (score 8):

`filesize` applied to the directory doesn't give the size of its contents. It returns the size of the filesystem node, which, in your case, takes 4kb. This size depends on the *amount* of the files in the directory.

To get the actual size of contents - you need to get the size of each file and summarize it.

Comment: but if after deleting 3 or 4 files, size of the folder is not 4096 then why its showing the same size?

Comment: @Ali Hassan: because the directory node with size of 4kb can fit hundreds of files. So either it stores 0 or 100 files - it will be anyway of size 4kb

Answer (score 1):

You can get your Total folder size and it Sub directory like this

```
$dir = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$size = 0;
foreach ( $dir as $file ) {
    $size += $file->getSize();
}
var_dump($size);
```

Also note that

> Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.