# How to get the directory size in php

Tags: php

i am building a storage system where i need to get the directory size how to get it?
i use this

```
$file_directory = './directory/path';
$output = exec('du -sk ' . $file_directory);
$filesize = trim(str_replace($file_directory, '', $output)) * 1024;$file_directory = './directory/path';
$output = exec('du -sk ' . $file_directory);
$filesize = trim(str_replace($file_directory, '', $output)) * 1024;
```

but its not give me proper response.
i want to give every user 10 Gb storage

Comment: read this one http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: Hi did you take a look a there already? (there is an alternative to the du variant using RecusiveDirectoryIterator instead)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163456/php-get-the-size-of-a-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This it will works for you

```
<?php
    $units = explode(' ', 'B KB MB GB TB PB');
    $SIZE_LIMIT = 5368709120; // 5 GB change it to 10 Gb
    $disk_used = foldersize("/folder/");

    $disk_remaining = $SIZE_LIMIT - $disk_used;

    echo("<html><body>");
    echo('diskspace used: ' . format_size($disk_used) . '<br>');
    echo( 'diskspace left: ' . format_size($disk_remaining) . '<br><hr>');
    echo("</body></html>");


function foldersize($path) {
    $total_size = 0;
    $files = scandir($path);
    $cleanPath = rtrim($path, '/'). '/';

    foreach($files as $t) {
        if ($t<>"." && $t<>"..") {
            $currentFile = $cleanPath . $t;
            if (is_dir($currentFile)) {
                $size = foldersize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            }
            else {
                $size = filesize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            }
        }   
    }

    return $total_size;
}


function format_size($size) {
    global $units;

    $mod = 1024;

    for ($i = 0; $size > $mod; $i++) {
        $size /= $mod;
    }

    $endIndex = strpos($size, ".")+3;

    return substr( $size, 0, $endIndex).' '.$units[$i];
}

?>
```

Comment: or check out the full question and all the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/php-get-directory-size