# how to create a folder in php and limit the upload in that folder

Tags: php

i want so set a limit on a folder which is being created by the user:

according to script below:

```
$root = "/users/homedir/";
if (!is_dir($root))
{
    @mkdir("users/homedir/", 0777);
```

The folder **homedir** should contain max 20 Mb of storage. If this is reached, the user can not upload into that folder anymore. 
How can i set those 20 Mb limit to that folder when it is created?

Comment: You can't set the limit on folder creation. You will need to monitor the size of the directory via other code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/php-get-directory-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a limit at the time of creation, but you can [check the directory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163456/php-get-the-size-of-a-directory) along with the size of the file being uploaded, and limit based on those values.