# Php folder space limit on server

Tags: php, directory

Hello everyone i have question that can help me very much.

In php can we create a space limit to the folder that on server to upload the data in that particular folder.

please help me

thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about a php file upload?

Comment: This can be done either with your OS tools for quotas on your file system, or within your application.  Either way, you'd need to be much more specific before a proper answer could be given.

Answer (score 2):

You can fake it by checking how much stuff is in a folder before "accepting" a new upload, but PHP itself does not have any kind of quota support - that's done at the file system level by the the operating system PHP is running under.

Answer (score 1):

Just substract [the size of the current folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/php-get-directory-size) from the quota size and compare to the size of the uploaded file.