# Managing ServerSide FileSystem through Web Application

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications, file-upload, filesystems

I am developing a web application that will manage directories and files through its web interface.

Developing a web interface is one part, and it is in advanced progress. However, I start thinking, how should I develop the server application, that will manage the files and directories based on user input.

The client will be created using standard tools:

1. HTML5
2. CSS3
3. JavaScript
4. PHP - Despite it is server side application, it will be responsible mostly for Dynamic Websites
5. MySQL - Despite it is server side application, it will be responsible mostly for keeping information about users, their settings, etc..

Would you advise me please, **what would be a server-side programming language of choice to manage server-side file system?** Is there **any API available**, that will allow me to do exactly what I wish? Is it possible to **manage the server-side file system in server-side JavaScript**, or should I chose another tool? Server-side JavaScript comes to my mind as a logical chocie, as I use it for the client side as well.

This is what I wish to achieve:

- To create new directories and files
- To delete directories and files
- To track the directory and file size
- To move files between directories
- To provide content of the directories and subdirectories

Ideally, the solution should be platform independent and should work on both, Linux Ubuntu and Windows Server OS.

I understand that my question is a bit broad. I would be thankful, **if you point me to the right direction**, which technologies to start studying, to be able to accomplish the above mentioned.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a very capable serverside language in your list.  PHP.

PHP can do all of the things you listed above... and a few you didn't list as well :)

> To create new directories and files

New files can be created with the [`touch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) function, and new directories with the [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php function.

> To delete directories and files

Deletion is done with [`rmdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) and [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

> To track the directory and file size

File sizes can be monitored using the [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function. Couldn't find a native folder size function but this Stack Overflow post may be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/478161/558021

> To move files between directories

Moving files and directories can be accomplished by using the `rename()` function.

> To provide content of the directories and subdirectories

One of the functions PHP gives us to scan folders is called [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) it glob - it allows you to find pathnames matching a pattern, so if you give it a wildcard character `*` it will find all the files in a certain location.

Comment: great answer. +1, the Answer contains all I needed to know. I know, PHP will be sufficient for my needs and I therefore can start exploring on my own. Thank you for providing the examples of the right functions to call. I am marking this as the *Accepted Answer*.