# how to get the size of folders in php?

Tags: php

i have a directory which has more than 10 folders. i want to know the size of each folder . i did like this but i did not show any thing. i also tired other method in which i can get the size of specific folder .any suggestion ?

```
enter code here

 $dir ="D:/WWebserver/Storage/" ;
 function folderSize ($dir)
 {
 $size = 0;
 foreach (glob(rtrim($dir, '/').'/*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $each) {
    $size += is_file($each) ? filesize($each) : folderSize($each);
 }
 return $size;
 echo $size ;
 }
```

Comment: here i can get only size of one folder

Comment: put the answer into your foreach loop

Comment: it shows some exception

Comment: Read this article : http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/folder-size-php and modify according to your need

Comment: yes... i got ... i am missing the full path

Comment: toldya, you just copy & paste it without editing first :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?
    $f = 'D:/WWebserver/Storage/';
    $obj = new COM ( 'scripting.filesystemobject' );
    if ( is_object ( $obj ) )
    {
        $ref = $obj->getfolder ( $f );
        echo 'Directory: ' . $f . ' => Size: ' . $ref->size;
        $obj = null;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'can not create object';
    }
?>
```

referring. 
[php get directory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/php-get-directory-size)

Comment: i can get only a specific folder in this way. i want more folder size . i have already tried this .

Comment: define "more". sub folder sizes also?

Comment: how can i define ? a small example

Comment: do you want subfolder's sizes also?

Comment: yes .... i only want the subfolder sizes

Comment: The given link gets you the sub folder sizes. follow it.

Comment: i got ... thanks.. i am missing the full path