# Laravel - calculate total size of directory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to get the total size of $directory in Laravel, so far I've only been able to get the size of a single file using the size function. There doesn't seem to be any examples or documentation of this?

Any input on this would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: With help of PHP. Refer this  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/php-get-directory-size

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think you can. Laravel 5 uses [Flysystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/api/) Library, which has a sole method for retrieving file size. So using Laravel's File Facade (or Flysystem), you're only left with:

```
    $file_size = 0;

    foreach( File::allFiles('FULL_PATH_TO_DIR') as $file)
    {
        $file_size += $file->getSize();
    }
    echo number_format($file_size / 1048576,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

laravel 8

```
  $imageSize = $request->file('file')->getSize();
    $fil->size = number_format($imageSize / 1048576,2);
```

**$file->size DB table Change It With Your Table**