# Can I know how is called a PHP function?

Tags: php, function

I'm writing a function that can returns an integer value or write this integer into a file.
I want this choice to be done just by the call of the function.
Can I do it ?

Here is the function :

```
function directory_space_used($directory) {
// Space used by the $directory
  ...
  if ( "call #1" ) return $space_used;
  if ( "call #2" ) {
    $file=fopen(path/to/file, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $space_used);
    fclose($file);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Call #1 :

```
$hyper_space = directory_space_used('awesome/directory');
echo "$hyper_space bytes used.";
```

Call #2 :

```
directory_space_used('awesome/directory'); // Write in file path/to/file
```

If it's not possible, I can use a 2nd parameter in the function but I want to keep the parameters' number as low as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: check this simple:-http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php

Comment: Thanks @Anant but this function (and the disk_free_space one) takes the whole filesystem, I just want the directory.
The function could be anything else, I just want to change the behavior if I call the function differently.

Comment: you can pass directory too.

Comment: Yes but on my server, it still takes the whole filesystem. Maybe there is a parameter I don't know ...

Comment: check the answers:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/php-get-directory-size . use them one-by-one and see which one works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a count in a session variable, but i'd suggest a second parameter. It's cleaner to maintain, and you can always set a default value, so that it's only used for one of the cases

```
function directory_space_used($directory, $tofile = false) {
// Space used by the $directory
...
if ( $tofile )  {
   $file=fopen(path/to/file, 'w');
   fwrite($file, $space_used);
   fclose($file);
}else{
   return $space_used;
}
  return null;
}
```

And then just call it like:

```
directory_space_used('....', true) // saves in a file
directory_space_used('....') // return int
```

Comment: Can you add a code example for a better understnding? You can doing it by using the edit link underneath your post.

Comment: @some1special : It won't be funny if I use a 2nd parameter :)

Comment: @reporter : Just look at the calls in my question. I wrote it as clear as possible, because the main code is not important.

Comment: @some1special your edit let your answer looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this magic constant

```
__FUNCTION__
```

and you can read about it
[here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Just make one more parameter on your function, and this parametter will be the name of the function that the request come from and after that you can use it in the if statement.

this is a pseudo code:

```
       //function that you want to compare
        function test1() {
        //do stuff here
        $session['function_name'] = __FUNCTTION__;
        directory_space_used($directory,$function_name);
        }

        //Other function that you want to compare
        function test2() {
        //do stuff here
        $session['function_name'] = __FUNCTTION__;
    }

function directory_space_used($directory) {
        // Space used by the $directory
          ...
           if(isset($session['function_name'])) {
          if ('test1' == $function_name ) return $space_used;
          if ( 'test2' == $function_name ) {
            $file=fopen(path/to/file, 'w');
            fwrite($file, $space_used);
            fclose($file);
          }
        } else {
//something else 
}

          return null;
        }
```

I think will be better option to use switch cases... this is just a note .

the test1 amd test2 can be anywhere in your php files and folders

Comment: My calls are in a main script, not in functions. If I create other functions, it will be hardier to maintain.

Comment: Yes, but any way you have to know from wich function is made the call of your function ? Or I missing something...

Comment: You can use session to keep the functions that you want to compare.. $session['function_name'] =  __FUNCTTION__; and this code put it in all function that you want to use for your function. After that add one more parameter to your function to check if has a session or not, and what is the name of the session (name of the function ) if you know what I mean ?

Comment: No, I want to know if the function is called with a = before (look at the 2 calls in my question)

Comment: What a heavy code ! And you still use a second parameter :)
I can just use the second parameter if I want (see @some1special's answer)

Comment: Okay, remove the parametter and check only the session inside the function. I was wrong for that, it's a session any way :) Just in your main function check for the session..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, it seems the better way is to put a second parameter in the function. Not as funny as I wanted, but it works easily, without using lots of code.