# Get the size of a folder in Amazon s3 using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to get the size of a folder without looping through all the files in laravel. The folder is in Amazon S3. My current code is:

```
$files = Storage::allFiles($dir);
foreach ($files as $file) {
     $size+= Storage::size($file);
}
```

I want to avoid the looping is there any way to accomplish this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/478161/7398574, see if it helps you..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to compute the size of a folder without recursively looping through it.

A quick command line solution is using `du`.

`du -hs /path/to/directory` will output the disk usage.

- `-h` is to get the numbers "human readable", e.g. get 140M instead of 143260 (size in KBytes)
- `-s` is for summary (otherwise you'll get not only the size of the folder but also for everything in the folder separately)

Referenced: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224/how-do-i-determine-the-total-size-of-a-directory-folder-from-the-command-line

Comment: Recently Amazon has updated its features I want to know whether they provide any method for this

Answer (score 4):

Using listContents you can get an array of files including filesizes and then you can map that array into a total size.

```
  $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
  $size = array_sum(array_map(function($file) {
    return (int)$file['size'];
  }, array_filter($disk->listContents('your_folder', true /*<- recursive*/), function($file) {
    return $file['type'] == 'file';
  })));
```

Answer (score 1):

The other option you have, if you can deal with a day old stats, is the newly released 'S3 Storage Inventory' feature.

S3 can put out a daily (or weekly) file that has an inventory of all of your objects in the folder, including size:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html

> Amazon S3 inventory is one of the tools Amazon S3 provides to help
>   manage your storage. You can simplify and speed up business workflows
>   and big data jobs using the Amazon S3 inventory, which provides a
>   scheduled alternative to the Amazon S3 synchronous List API operation.
>   Amazon S3 inventory provides a comma-separated values (CSV) flat-file
>   output of your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or
>   weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects
>   that have names that begin with a common string).
>
> You can configure what object metadata to include in the inventory,
>   whether to list all object versions or only current versions, where to
>   store the inventory list flat-file output, and whether to generate the
>   inventory on a daily or weekly basis. You can have multiple inventory
>   lists configured for a bucket. For information about pricing, see
>   Amazon S3 Pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudWatch provides automatic metrics for the number of objects stored in a bucket and the storage space occupied. I'm not sure how often these metrics are updated, but that would be the simplest to use. However, this measures the **whole bucket** rather than just a particular folder.

See: [Amazon Simple Storage Service Metrics and Dimensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/s3-metricscollected.html)