# PHP: How to delete all subfolders (only 1MB or smaller in size) and wipe out all its files?

Tags: php

I need to put condition only delete all folders that have 1mb and smaller in size.

```
$dir ="thousandfolders";

   function del($dir) { 
      foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) 
      { 
        if(is_dir($file))
            del($file); 
      } 
      rmdir($dir); 
    }
```

Comment: Have you tired searching. It appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/how-to-get-directory-size-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get directory size in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478121/how-to-get-directory-size-in-php)